# How to parse string in react to render html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a very basic blog type app with a MERN stack and have it to the point where I can have a very simple post of just text.  Can anyone suggest how I could parse that string to also render HTML in my content?

So a post would look like

**Bold Text** with [a link](https://#)

instead of

`<b> Bold  Text with <a href="#"> a link</a></b>`

One idea I had was to try and use `DOMParser` in the component, something like

```
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const parsedContent = parser.parseFromString(post.description, 'text/html');

// and then in the render just print it out
<div className='content'>
{parsedContent} 
</div>
```

That of course did not work because that is returning an entire `html` object and React errors with `Objects are not valid as a React child.. if you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

What would be the proper way to parse that string and render the HTML in my content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just try this way:

```
const Test = () => {
    const text = '<b> Bold  Text with <a href="#"> a link</a></b>';

    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }} />;
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! I am not too worried about security for this one so willing to live dangerously ;)